# Dropdownlist in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to display multiple DropDownList MVC5. I have corresponding classes  for the same. Kindly advise for the same. I am totally new to MVC.Value (SysId) needs to stored in database and description will be displayed in page. There are 4 dropdownlists in web page. All classes have same properties.

Kindly help for the same ..

```
public ActionResult Registration()
{
   RegistrationClass obj = new RegistrationClass();
   obj = obj.getAllDropdown();
   return View(obj);
}
public class RegistrationClass
{

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Name")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name can not be more than 50 characters ")]
        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string name { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Gender")]
        [DisplayName("Gender")]
        public string gender { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Date of Birth")]
        [DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date,ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date ")]
        public DateTime dob { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Caste")]
        public List<Caste> lcaste { get; set; }
        public int cast_id { get; set; }

       public RegistrationClass getAllDropdown()
        {
            RegistrationClass obj = new RegistrationClass();
            Connection cobj = new Connection();
            string strConn = cobj.getConnectionString();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_get_preference_dropdown", con);
            SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ada.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++ )
                {
                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["code"].ToString() == "04") // Set Caste Preference
                    {
                        lcaste = new List<Caste>();

                        Caste obj1 = new Caste();
                        obj1.decription = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["description"].ToString();
                        obj1.sysId = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"]);
                        //obj1.isChecked = "N";
                        lcaste.Add(obj1);
                        obj.lcaste = lcaste;
                        continue;
                    }
                }


            }

            return obj;
        }

public class Caste
    {
        public int sysId { get; set; }
        public string decription { get; set; }
        public string isChecked { get; set; }

    }
}


@model Matrimony.Models.RegistrationClass
<tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.subcaste)
                                </td>
                                <td>

                                   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.cast_id, new SelectList(Model.lcaste))

                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved this by adding simple option tags.

```
<td>
<select name="cast_id">
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.lcaste.Count; i++)
    {
       <option value=@Model.lcaste[i].sysId>@Model.lcaste[i].decription</option>
    }

</select>

</td>
```

The **name** property of select will get the selected item's value in post method. Accordingly we can handle it in controller. I also added property in my model class to store value as

```
public int cast_id { get; set; }
public List<Caste> lcaste { get; set; }
```